# What's the best way to choose between twisty and plus/minus icon?

Tags: icons, tables

When designing collapse and expandable rows, are there certain ways to choose between using a twisty icon vs a plus/minus icon?

Below are examples I've taken from google search ---

**With a twisty icon:**
[image]

**With plus/minus icon:**
[image]

Comment: This thread might also be of help to you: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/37686/how-should-you-show-that-an-accordion-is-expanded

Answer (score 2):

I think plus/minus is better choice for a number of reasons:

1. User clearly understand this row has child rows
2. Minus sign also clearly states user can close it
3. It represents tree view with perfect understanding

But plus/minus looks a bit boring if not designed well similar to your second example. So design these in way that it looks apealing to users.

Answer (score 1):

I think both are equally clear however I would never nest the twisty arrows.  They feel more like a single level accordion so here are the questions I ask when deciding...

1. If there are multiple levels of hidden child items then use + and -
2. If there is only a single level of hidden items then either one acceptable
3. If I can click on the entire row to expand/collapse children then the twisty arrow is preferred
4. If I need the user to click the icon directly (to allow selection of text in the same row) then + and - is preferred

Since your examples show multiple levels of nested children and data that a user may need to select with a mouse drag then I would use a nice sized + and - squares that the user can click on to expand and collapse the child rows below it.